# impact of activity stopped or paused

Tags: android

I went to lot of discussion on activity life-cycle methods onStop() and onPause() etc, but they are just callbacks to give app a chance to do stuffs like saving data or unbinding resources.

My question is about stop/pause actions (not onStop/onPause functions) what process takes over when activity is stopped or paused?

1. Activity's Hide/overlap is caused by stop/pause or hide/overlap triggers stop/pause?
2. In "pause" I guess UI thread is running and just not sent any touch event, am I correct?
3. In "stop" I guess UI thread is suspended (thread blocked) and also do not get any touch events, I am wrong?
4. what else happens apart from these ?

Example: suppose Android web browser is just loading a webpage and immediately stopped (put in background) I guess network thread will not be stopped here, will the page rendering completes while it remains in background?

Comment: Did you read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar isnt this talking about callbacks?

Comment: He mentions the callbacks, but the rest of the question is about the states themselves.

Comment: From what I read the developer docs do talk about the state of the activities as well (for example what it means if an activity is paused and what should happen). Also it says if an activity is paused it is only partially visible. This in turn answers the question about user interaction, as only the top level activity receives user input.

Comment: Also my comment wasn't meant to be a RTFM but to enquiry on which level of understanding we're talking here.

Comment: like @ThorstenDittmar mentioned i am interested in "states", i have stated the example of mobile browser in my question. What is the effect of these states at cpu/process/thread levels, when i hide the opera browser but it completes rendering that means ui threads keep running when state is "stopped"